# How to skew image with CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, transform, skew

I want to skew an image like this

[image]

It working when I apply for `div`

[image]

now I want to use this code for `img` tag it doesn't work.

[image]

Here is my live code:

https://jsfiddle.net/dbkvdq3u/5/

```css
.steps-widget .step-img-box {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  height: 60px;
}
.steps-widget .step-img-box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
}
.steps-widget .step-img-box:after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="step-img-box">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/E7atspO.jpg" alt="Image">
</div>
<!-- end step-img-box -->
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/dbkvdq3u/6/ like this?

Comment: Your example image doesn't look skewed - it looks like a white mask has been placed around it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *div, etc img* but have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368404/how-to-create-a-polygon-shape-div-with-css/30370429#30370429). The same skew approach without `overflow:hidden` on parent should work for you.

Comment: Your Code is not up to the mark. You have put the skewness Before and after div containing box. You should put your code for your image as well.

Comment: Sorry all guys, I have updated my question :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, but I think I can archive this by using CSS.

Comment: @TheHung: Using `skew`, you can't achieve this using a single `img` element (because you can't skew half in one direction and half in another). Have a look at the link that I provided in my previous comment. That should be simple enough to adapt to `img` tags. Or you could have a look at SVG/CSS clip-path. It would have worked for a solid color probably because you added a background color to the pseudo elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use pseudo elements, using the background position property to align the two 'halfs' of the image:

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-size: 300px 300px;
}
div:before {
  transform: skewY(10deg);
}
div:after {
  left: 50%;
  background-position: -100% 0;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
}
.sk:before, .sk:after{  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300);}
.sk2:before, .sk2:after{  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400);}
```

```html
<div class="sk"></div>
<div class="sk2"></div>
```

Comment: thanks @jbutler483 excellent answer. I have a minor issue that in case I want to change background-image so I've tried add another class called `bg-1` and add `background-image` to this but it doesn't work.

Comment: @TheHung Please see my edit. I've used a class to add the `:before` and `:after` elements

Comment: @jbutler483 Thank you so much. Excellent answer.