# Image with right edge triangle

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am some time trying to make a complicated effect on the image, I made some attempts however not got it. I need this effect only in css without using javascript.

[image]

CSS

```
.container{
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #0c2f45;
}

.image-container {
    background-color: #194c6e;
    width: 266px;
}

.image-container img{
    width: 250px;
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74yv2str/)

Comment: You can only do it with a mask

Comment: Can you change your markup?

Comment: yes change the markup

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368404/how-to-create-a-polygon-shape-div-with-css/30370429#30370429). It is almost similar to what you need.

Comment: Check this out --> http://jsfiddle.net/74yv2str/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve something like this through a couple of transformed pseudo elements*. By skewing the two pesudos, you can create the triangular effect.

A quick demo would be:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/200);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  background: tomato;
  border-left: 10px solid firebrick;
  left: 80%;
}
div:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: skewX(10deg);
}
div:after {
  top: 50%;
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

<sup>* this would assume you wish to have a solid colour on the right hand side</sup>