# Triangle bottom CSS with background

Tags: html, css

***I know it's duplicated from this [How to create a polygon shape div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368404/how-to-create-a-polygon-shape-div-with-css) , but I don't know how to fix it on the bottom. I really tried everything, and I don't understand how it's done. Can someone help me with this please? ***

I am slicing a design I received. But now I walk into a problem.

I want to cut the background of my slider in a triangle shape ( see image ).

How can I do this in CSS3?

NOTE: It has to be responsive.

[image]

Comment: i wonder why this got negative voted, anyway, people won't answer when they know what happend to people who answer to negative voted post ...

Comment: @Froggiz The reason this topic received some negative votes comes from the fact it exists one topic for this question, and even if it is not the exact same problem as the OP faces, the OP didn't showed a proof of effort, neither a single line of code.

Comment: I would create two triangles using the containers before and after pseudo-elements. This should help you get started: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/CSS-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-practice

Comment: As the person who wrote the accepted answer to the linked question, I can definitely help to clarify your queries but you should specify what was the problem and also show your code. Also, have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wbg5rxu/1/) that I had provided in comments there. It is again a triangular cut on the left (instead of bottom) but it is also a slider (hover the image to see the slider in action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `clip-path` would be best in this situation. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmw0t7yL/)

```
background-image: url('image.jpg');
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80%);
```

Comment: You're my hero, I've been looking for this for so long!

Comment: glad to help! good luck! also check out this site if you need different shapes http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: ah yes, in that case you'll need to use the `:before` and `:after` methods, like the question you linked. this tool might help http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/