# css clip path alternative

Tags: html, css, transform, css-shapes

I am trying to do a banner for my website, a bit differently.

I want bottom border, to be kind of "arrow down" looking

Something like this: [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qkvz8z1j/)

```css
.indexBanner {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFUnt.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #404040;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 85%, 50% 100%, 0 85%, 0 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="indexBanner"></div>
```

But currently I am using clip-path, which is not supported by Firefox and IE.
And also you can see that the "arrow shaped" border is a bit messy.

I've also tried `transform: skew` in which case the result was more of a "chat bubble" kind of effect.

Is there any way to do this, because I am all out of ideas.

Comment: You can use the `skew` approach mentioned in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368404/how-to-create-a-polygon-shape-div/30370429#30370429. I don't understand what you meant by "chat bubble" effect. Maybe if you show a demo, I can help to fine tune it. SVG would be your best bet though.

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/qkvz8z1j/10/)

Comment: Just noting that Firefox has supported `clip-path` with a reference to an SVG `<clipPath>` element for ages and with basic shapes like `polygon` for about a year (unprefixed). It needs the `layout.css.clip-path-shapes.enabled` flag set to `true` in `about:config` to work.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/h18w341m/

```css
.indexBanner {
  background-image: url('http://nauci.se/Flipo/assets/images/study.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #404040;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.indexBanner:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50vw solid white;
  border-right: 50vw solid white;
  border-top: 15vw solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="indexBanner"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried changing the arrow-border to look less messy.

https://jsfiddle.net/night11/b7ch05Ln/ - updated

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 1%, 100% 0, 100% 60%, 50% 100%, 0 60%);
```

Comment: Please check your link. I guess this jfiddle is for another issue.

Comment: Thanks for bringing to notice :)